# Column elements are not scrollable in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll

I also tried to wrap the second `column` in `SingleChildScrollView` but that didn't work either.
Please tell me a solution.
The screen is not scrolling. When I delete the upper element only then another comes.
Here is my code.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getAppointments(email),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  AppointmentsUser appointments =
                      snapshot.data[index];

                  return Column(children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        appointments.service,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.people,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("Seller: ${appointments.seller}"),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("Date: ${appointments.date}"),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("Time: ${appointments.time}"),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                  ]);
                }
              );
            } 
            return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `ListView` also has a scroll and the single child ScrollView also has a scroll. Removing either one should let you scroll through the content. You can either add a `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to the `Listview` or remove `SingleChildScrollView` since the ListView has got a scroll by default.

```dart
ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//add this line
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,// <=== add this line
...
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: Sure @SaeedZhiany I'll try my best to improve quality of answers. Thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add this, it works fine from my side.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),   
    ........
),
```